# Large overhead in CUDA kernel launch outside GPU execution

Tags: linux, cuda

I am measuring the running time of kernels, as seen from a CPU thread, by measuring the interval from before launching a kernel to after a cudaDeviceSynchronize (using gettimeofday). I have a cudaDeviceSynchronize before I start recording the interval. I also instrument the kernels to record the timestamp on the GPU (using clock64) at the start of the kernel by thread(0,0,0) of each block from block(0,0,0) to block(occupancy-1,0,0) to an array of size equal to number of SMs. Every thread at the end of the kernel code, updates the timestamp to another array (of the same size) at the index equal to the index of the SM it runs on.

The intervals calculated from the two arrays are 60-70% of that measured from the CPU thread.

For example, on a K40, while gettimeofday gives an interval of 140ms, the avg of  intervals calculated from GPU timestamps is only 100ms. I have experimented with many grid sizes (15 blocks to 6K blocks) but have found similar behavior so far.

```
__global__ void some_kernel(long long *d_start, long long *d_end){
     if(threadIdx.x==0){
        d_start[blockIdx.x] = clock64();
     }
     //some_kernel code
     d_end[blockIdx.x] = clock64();
}
```

Does this seem possible to the experts?

Comment: The prevailing wisdom is that it is a bad idea to try converting count/count64 output to a time because of uncertainty regarding clock frequency. But beyond a yes or no (ie. an opinion), what sort of answer are you expecting here?

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the comment. But for the same platform, the clock64 output should at least be related to the gettimeofday output by the same factor or no? Also I am expecting to get an idea of how much the latency in HW for thread block dispatching can be.

Comment: No. Your GPU (like most modern microprocessors) using a dynamic clock rate which can vary according to device state (power, temperature, load). You can't know what that was (or even whether it remained constant) between successive calls to clock. Further, the compiler/assembler can (and does) reorder instructions. So you can't even be sure that the clock measurements coincide to the kernel C code you are timing, unless you have disassembled the SASS code and analysed it. Have you done that?

Comment: Thanks @talonmies for the explanation. I haven't yet analyzed the SASS, I was going to do that next. If I disable boost, can I assume that the variability of frequency would be eliminated?

Comment: I think the described measurement method also makes no sense. Why would there be a need for averaging anything, if you are interested in "overhead"?  The timing measurement I would be interested in would be the difference between the *earliest* timestamp recorded by *any thread*, and the *latest* time stamp recorded by *any thread*.  You haven't shown a scrap of code (makes for a less than stellar question on SO, IMO), but in *most* cuda kernels of any size, some threads start before others, and some finish before others.  It's unclear what you are trying to measure and the logic of the method

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the feedback. What I meant when I mentioned averaging is that of the interval calculated over several timesteps of running the program. I have added code that I use when the grid size is equal to the occupancy. Would there be any significant error if I let thread(0,0,0) to record the timestamp? I do let every thread update the end timestamp.

Comment: How do you know that thread 0 (or warp 0, if you prefer) is the first one kicked off in the block?  If you have multiple blocks, how do you know which block gets executed first?  last?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I agree that I do not know for sure if thread 0 is the first to be scheduled by the HW. But the time to run all the thread blocks when I reduce the grid size to be equal to occupancy (6 blocks/SM x 15 SMs) is 1-2ms and this is very small compared to the running time (100ms) when I launch the kernel keeping the original grid size unchanged (6K+ blocks). So even if thread 0 was not the first to start, the measurement error is 1-2%. I know for sure that thread 0 started before any thread in blocks 90 through end.

Comment: @Curious: You can't know that. The order in which blocks run is not predictable. Block 0 need not be the first block scheduled and it need not start before block 90.

Comment: clock64 is based upon GPU clock frequency. K40 has a special register called %globaltimer time will return a value reported in ns. If the profiler is not running this will report in 1us granularity. You can use inline PTX to access the register. It still has very very small drift from CPU tsc timer so you will still be required to synchronize CPU and GPU timers if you want to correlate the results on a time. If you just want duration it will work fine. You can also use inline PTX to read %smid to understand scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this seem possible to the experts?

I suppose anything is possible for code you haven't shown.  After all, you may just have a silly bug in any of your computation arithmetic.  But if the question is "is it sensible that there should be 40ms of unaccounted-for time overhead on a kernel launch, for a kernel that takes ~140ms to execute?" I would say no.

I believe the method I outlined in the comments is reasonably accurate.  Take the minimum `clock64()` timestamp from any thread in the grid (but see note below regarding SM restriction).  Compare it to the maximum time stamp of any thread in the grid.  The difference will be comparable to the reported execution time of `gettimeofday()` to within 2 percent, according to my testing.

Here is my test case:

```
$ cat t1040.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define LS_MAX 2000000000U
#define MAX_SM 64

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

__device__ int result;
__device__ unsigned long long t_start[MAX_SM];
__device__ unsigned long long t_end[MAX_SM];

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

__device__ __inline__ uint32_t __mysmid(){
  uint32_t smid;
  asm volatile("mov.u32 %0, %%smid;" : "=r"(smid));
  return smid;}

__global__ void kernel(unsigned ls){

  unsigned long long int ts = clock64();
  unsigned my_sm = __mysmid();
  atomicMin(t_start+my_sm, ts);
  // junk code to waste time
  int tv = ts&0x1F;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < ls; i++){
    tv &= (ts+i);}
  result = tv;
  // end of junk code
  ts = clock64();
  atomicMax(t_end+my_sm, ts);

}

// optional command line parameter 1 = kernel duration, parameter 2 = number of blocks, parameter 3 = number of threads per block
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 unsigned ls;
 if (argc > 1) ls = atoi(argv[1]);
 else ls = 1000000;
 if (ls > LS_MAX) ls = LS_MAX;
 int num_sms = 0;
 cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&num_sms, cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount, 0);
 cudaCheckErrors("cuda get attribute fail");
 int gpu_clk = 0;
 cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&gpu_clk, cudaDevAttrClockRate, 0);
 if ((num_sms < 1) || (num_sms > MAX_SM)) {printf("invalid sm count: %d\n", num_sms); return 1;}
 unsigned blks;
 if (argc > 2) blks = atoi(argv[2]);
 else blks = num_sms;
 if ((blks < 1) || (blks > 0x3FFFFFFF)) {printf("invalid blocks: %d\n", blks); return 1;}
 unsigned ntpb;
 if (argc > 3) ntpb = atoi(argv[3]);
 else ntpb = 256;
 if ((ntpb < 1) || (ntpb > 1024)) {printf("invalid threads: %d\n", ntpb); return 1;}
 kernel<<<1,1>>>(100);  // warm up
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
 unsigned long long *h_start, *h_end;
 h_start = new unsigned long long[num_sms];
 h_end = new unsigned long long[num_sms];
 for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++){
   h_start[i] = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
   h_end[i] = 0;}
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol(t_start, h_start, num_sms*sizeof(unsigned long long));
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol(t_end, h_end, num_sms*sizeof(unsigned long long));
 unsigned long long htime = dtime_usec(0);
 kernel<<<blks,ntpb>>>(ls);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 htime = dtime_usec(htime);
 cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(h_start, t_start, num_sms*sizeof(unsigned long long));
 cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(h_end, t_end, num_sms*sizeof(unsigned long long));
 cudaCheckErrors("some error");
 printf("host elapsed time (ms): %f \n device sm clocks:\n start:", htime/1000.0f);
 unsigned long long max_diff = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++) {printf(" %12lu  ", h_start[i]);}
 printf("\n end:  ");
 for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++) {printf(" %12lu  ", h_end[i]);}
 for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++) if ((h_start[i] != 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL) && (h_end[i] != 0) && ((h_end[i]-h_start[i]) > max_diff)) max_diff=(h_end[i]-h_start[i]);
 printf("\n max diff clks: %lu\nmax diff kernel time (ms): %f\n", max_diff, max_diff/(float)(gpu_clk));
 return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1040 t1040.cu -arch=sm_35
$ ./t1040 1000000 1000 128
host elapsed time (ms): 2128.818115
 device sm clocks:
 start:      3484744        3484724
 end:     2219687393     2228431323
 max diff clks: 2224946599
max diff kernel time (ms): 2128.117432
$
```

Notes:

1. This code can only be run on a cc3.5 or higher GPU due to the use of 64-bit `atomicMin` and `atomicMax`.
2. I've run it on a variety of grid configurations, on both a GT640 (very low end cc3.5 device) and K40c (high end) and the timing results between host and device agree to within 2% (for reasonably long kernel execution times.  If you pass `1` as the command line parameter, with very small grid sizes, the kernel execution time will be very short (nanoseconds) whereas the host will see about 10-20us.  This *is* kernel launch overhead being measured.  So the 2% number is for kernels that take much longer than 20us to execute).
3. It accepts 3 (optional) command line parameters, the first of which varies the amount of time the kernel will execute.
4. My timestamping is done on a *per-SM* basis, because the `clock64()` resource is [indicated to be](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function) a *per-SM* resource.  The sm clocks are not guaranteed to be synchronized between SMs.
5. You can modify the grid dimensions.  The second optional command line parameter specifies the number of blocks to launch.  The third optional command line parameter specifies the number of threads per block. The timing methodology I have shown here should not be dependent on number of blocks launched or number of threads per block.  If you specify fewer blocks than SMs, the code should ignore "unused" SM data.

Comment: In the lines `for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++) {printf(" %12lu  ", h_start[i]); if (h_start[i] < min_ts) min_ts = h_start[i];}
 printf("\n end:  ");
 for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++) {printf(" %12lu  ", h_end[i]);  if (h_end[i] > max_ts) max_ts = h_end[i];}`, can we compare timestamps from two different SMs?

Comment: no we can't  (as per my note 4) I posted the wrong code, sorry.  I've updated it now.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Crovella . I am trying out your code on my test kernel now. But I think there can still be some error in measurement even considering the maximum interval as in `for (int i = 0; i < num_sms; i++) if ((h_end[i]-h_start[i]) > max_diff) max_diff=(h_end[i]-h_start[i]);`. The first thread to kick off may have been on a different SM. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, there can still be some error in measurement if the SM activity is staggered in time (i.e. SM_A starts before SM_B, *and* SM_A ends before SM_B).  However: 1. I don't know how to work around that because I'm unaware of a global time register that I can read in device code 2. In my testing it seemed to be not a significant source of error; certainly my method does not produce results that are off by 40%, which seemed to be your contention.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying....yes, I agree that such error cannot be the cause of the anomaly of measurements.